# PHP Generate Unique Order Number with Date

Tags: php, date, time, format

I want to generate unique identificator in following 12 numeric format:

```
YYYYMMDDXXXX
```

Example:

```
201403052318
```

Where:

YYYYMMDD is a current date value and other XXXX is randomly generated value.

```
$today = date("Ymd");
$rand = sprintf("%04d", rand(0,9999));
$unique = $today . $rand;
```

Daily required unique volume is about 100. What methods using PHP should I use to prevent possible duplicates in rand values or make all id maximum unique? Maybe possible use current time functions to compact these numbers in last 4 characters?

EDITED:
Unique value connected to MySQL database as prime index of table. It is initial values not connected to any stored information in database.

Comment: Is there a database involved? Are you trying to simply create an array of random numbers (without duplicates) initially and use it elsewhere? How do you plan to access this script? Via CLI or through an HTTP request? Please add more details to your question to get more accurate answers.

Comment: Do you really need a random number here or just something pseudo-unique?

Comment: pseudo-unique whatever, is that possible to compact hour-min-sec into as last 4 chars to escape from random?

Comment: @KenTang, Then you can have your `$rand` variable like this.. `$rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())),0,4));`

Answer (score 15):

You can't rely on `rand()` , There is a possibility you will generate a duplicate (Pretty rare for a `rand(0,9999)` to generate a duplicate, but that will at some point).

So instead of going for `rand()`, just create an incremental value (say.. starting from 1) and append to your generated date.

Next time when you regenerate a new id, grab that incremental value's (say if you had stored it somewhere.. must be 1 right ?) status, increment it and append it to your new date.

#### Not an ideal solution.. (Critics welcome)

You can make use of a `uniqid` coupled with `sha-1` and `time` and do a `substr()` on them for first 4 chars.

```
<?php
$today = date("Ymd");
$rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())),0,4));
echo $unique = $today . $rand;
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
201403094B3F
```

Comment: This answer is good, but rare?  You'll necessarily generate a duplicate in 10,000 samples, and probably _much_ sooner than that.  Think birthday paradox.  Also, it would be good to add a comment about catching overflow of that counter and handling it.

Answer (score 8):

I needed to do something similar, a solution that would keep time and also keep the id unique and i ended up with a solution to use `PHP` [function](http://pk1.php.net/time) `time()` like this

`$reference_number = 'BFF-' . time()`; you can change the `BFF` to something that makes more sense to your business logic.

My unique reference id looks like `BFF-1393327176` and the number can be converted from Unix to real time which will give you, `Tue, 25 Feb 2014 11:19:36`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If the unique values generated once, you just need to make conditional choice for the rand value and store the value in an array which is going to be the condition -*using [inarray](https://www.php.net/in_array)*-:

```
$amount = 100; // the amount of ids
$previousValues = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++){    
    $rand = rand(0,9999);
    while (in_array($rand, $previousValues)){
        $rand = rand(0, 9999);
    }
    $previousValues[] = $rand;
    $today = date("Ymd");
    $unique = $today.$rand;
    echo $unique."\n";
}
```

Checkout <kbd>[this demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ziv-ua8)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for creating unique "Unique Order Number" is following, I assume that you have **orders** table and field **order_number**, then the code is:

```
$orderNumber = DB::table('orders')->max('order_number') + random_int(10, 100);
```

If first order number is inserted as "100000000000" that method will give you this numbers:

```
100000000025
100000000056
100000000089
100000000123
100000000199
100000000232
100000000249
```

with that approach there is no possibility for non-unique number, but cons is that each number is greater the previous (not 100% random) but that approach is acceptable for most of the cases.